# How to know the cause of reboot with Watchdog in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, reboot, watchdog

I'm trying to recognize the reason cause reboot with Watchdog in Linux. In details, I use iMX8MM and Yocto OS image.

It's have a watchdog hardware(and a WD SW) and it's working good. Now, I wanna know the reason of the last reboot. I use WIOF_GETBOOTSTATUE flag to read state. This is a statement:

```
if (ioctl(fd, WDIOC_GETBOOTSTATUS , &bootstatus) == 0) {
      fprintf(stdout, "Last boot is caused by : %s\n",
         (bootstatus != 0) ? "Watchdog" : "Power-On-Reset");
```

But with any case, I still receive one result: **Power-On-Reset**

Case 1: I wrote a application. In the first 5 sec, It will send a ping message to watchdog. From there, It's will no longer send anything. After 60s, my device is reboot. But then, I check WDIOC_GETBOOTSTATUS flag, I still receive: **Power-On-Reset**
--> It should be **Watchdog**, right ?

Case 2: I unplug the power cable and plug it in again. And I get : **Power-On-Reset** --> Correctly.

Did I do the right thing? If not, what should I do ?

Thank you so much,

Toan

Comment: Such important information, don't you find this in `/var/log/messages`, which you can read using `dmesg`?

Comment: As I know, **/var/log/messages** is only contains log from current boot. **dmesg** is the same.

Comment: Which I want to know is reason of reboot in the last reboot.

Comment: Which watchdog driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using imx2+.

Comment: @ToanVnET If that is using the [imx2_wdt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/watchdog/imx2_wdt.c) driver, it looks like the bootstatus gets set to one of two different values by the driver's `imx2_wdt_probe()` function. First it reads the status register: `regmap_read(wdev->regmap, IMX2_WDT_WRSR, &val);`. Then it converts it to a boot status value: `wdog->bootstatus = val & IMX2_WDT_WRSR_TOUT ? WDIOF_CARDRESET : 0;`.  The `IMX2_WDT_WRSR_TOUT` bit means "Reset due to Timeout". I don't know why that bit isn't getting set.

Comment: Hi @IanAbbott, I also check imx2_wdt.c in watchdog driver. As you said, it's quite different with [imx2_wdt driver](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/imx2__wdt_8c_source.html#l00050). I'm trying to add function, but it seems complex. Beside that, I found other ways to read reboot status. It's SRSR. The SRSR is a write to one clear register which records the source of the reset events for the chip. It has address: `3039_0000h base + 5Ch offset = 3039_005Ch`. But I don't know how to read it. Do you have any ideas ?